# jquery jscrollpane-2.0.0beta10 can't get iframe content to show scrollbars

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I can't get my iframe content to show a scrollbar.
I believe i've been thorough in following the examples on the jscrollpane site.

I also debugged the jscrollpane js, and it turns out that contentHeight===paneHeight in initialise(), and that prevents the scrollbars from showing. contentHeight should be > paneHeight for my iframe's content, i think.

A demo of the problem is on http://mediabeez.ws/new_interface/
I will greatly appreciate tips / clues / fixes.

If we can get this fixed, i'll make a few nice themes for jscrollpane and donate 'm back to the project owner, k? :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the specific examples of using jScrollPane inside an iframe on the jScrollPane site?

1. The first approach puts the jScrollPane code in the loaded page and uses the full body scroll approach: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/iframe.html
2. The second approach has the jScrollPane code in the containing page but unfortunately is less functional due to security restrictions in the browser: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/iframe2.html

Comment: You don't need to manually initialise the scrollpane at the bottom of your loaded page - the document resize handler is triggered on ready and does this...

Comment: But it doesn't fix the problem though :(